# objective-c memory access failure

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm new to ios programming. I've read through the Apple developer memory guide and ARC guide, and I thought I already understood the memory management, but in fact I didn't.

Please help me identify where's wrong and why it's wrong, thanks.

First of all, the whole program, if I'm not wrong, is ARC enabled.

```
    NSDate *expireDate = nil;
    //using debug, expiresIn = 86400
    id expiresIn = [responseObject valueForKey:@"expires_in"];
    if (expiresIn != nil && ![expiresIn isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        //using debug, expireDate = currentDate + 1day
        expireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[expiresIn doubleValue]];
    }
    [credential setExpiration:expireDate];
```

and see setExpiration implementation in credential,

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSDate *expiration;
- (void)setExpiration:(NSDate *)expireDate
{
    //using debug, expireDate = currentDate + 1day
    if (!expireDate) {
        return;
    }
    // oops, the following line, caused exc_bad_access 
    //  (code = 2, address=0xxxxxxx)
    // and after the exception occurs, expireDate = nil in debug window
    self.expiration = expireDate;
}
```

The error is that, the self.expiration = expireDate causes memory access failure exception (exc_bad_access), which make me confused. Will expireDate be freed somewhere in between the if(!expireDate) and self.expiration=expireDate?

I don't really understand why this happens, please help.

Thanks again.

===========

Thanks for the answer,

I changed to _expiration = expireDate, then the exception is gone.

However, why the following for NSString works (without exception), but the NSDate * doesn't?

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSString *refreshToken;
- (void)setRefreshToken:(NSString *)refreshToken
{
    if (!refreshToken) {
        return;
    }

    self.refreshToken = refreshToken;
}
```

Comment: hi, the error is in comment, thanks. I'll make it more clear.

Comment: You should change !refreshToken in refreshToken == nil. It's no problem in this case (or iOS in general), but this won't work in some other programming languages. It's better practise to use refreshToken == nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.expiration = expireDate;` should be `_expiration = expireDate;`.

You're getting an error because `self.expiration = expireDate;` sets up an infinitely recursive call to `setExpiration` which results in a stack overflow.

Comment: hi, it works, thanks. pls see another question in the post. I made an edit.

Comment: _Will `expireDate` be freed somewhere in between the `if(!expireDate)` and `_expiration=expireDate`?_ No. Also, additional questions should be asked as separate SO questions.

Comment: Hi neilco, thank you. one more, see the above NSString example, there's no exception for this one.

Comment: And, why there is a cycle retain for self.Expiration = expireDate?

Comment: Having just tested it, the `NSString` example does result in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception due to a stack overflow. As I would expect.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize setExpiration is a grammar cookie setter method which will be called in self.expiration= syntax.

Answer (score 1):

cycle retain `self.expiration = expireDate;`
just :

```
- (void)setExpiration:(NSDate *)expireDate
{
    expiration = expireDate;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. One more, see the above NSString example, there's no exception for this one. Why is it so?

Comment: @user534498 The same issue, it would make memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this
**.h file**

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSDate *expiration;
```

**.m file**

```
@synthesize  expiration = _expiration;

- (void)setExpiration:(NSDate *)expireDate
{
    //using debug, expireDate = currentDate + 1day
    if (!expireDate) {
        return;
    }

    self.expiration = expireDate;
}
```